# Gerar caracteres aleatórios de forma segura

Tags: javascript, criptografia

Olá, sou novo em javascript e estou usando a seguinte função para embaralhar caracteres de uma string em um gerador de senhas que estou tentando desenvolver:

```
function shuffle(string) {
    "use strict";
    var parts = string.split('');
    for (var i = parts.length; i > 0;) {
        var random = parseInt(Math.random() * i);
        var temp = parts[--i];
        parts[i] = parts[random];
        parts[random] = temp;
    }
    return parts.join('');
}
```

Porém segundo fui informado, usar `Math.random()` não é muito seguro para esse propósito. Gostaria de saber como posso adaptar minha função então usando `window.crypto.getRandomValues()` que me informaram ser mais seguro.

Grato por qualquer ajuda!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pesquisando um pouco mais acabei achando a solução. Segue código:

```
function generateRandomNumber(){
    "use strict";

    // se o browser tiver suporte à getRandomValues()
    if (Uint32Array && window.crypto && window.crypto.getRandomValues) { 
        var numbers = new Uint32Array(1);
        window.crypto.getRandomValues(numbers);
        return numbers[0] * Math.pow(2,-32);

    // caso não tenha, é utilizado Math.random
    } else {
        return Math.random();
    }
}

function shuffle(string) {
    "use strict";
    var parts = string.split('');

    for (var i = parts.length; i > 0;) {
        var random = parseInt(generateRandomNumber() * i); // aqui é chamada a função que gera o número aleatório
        var temp = parts[--i];
        parts[i] = parts[random];
        parts[random] = temp;
    }

    return parts.join('');
}
```

Referência:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13694626/generating-random-numbers-0-to-1-with-crypto-generatevalues